# Как сделать выборку всех записей из двух таблиц, кроме тех которые есть у одной и другой

Tags: sql, postgresql

Допустим есть таблицы **A** и **B** . У **A** есть поля **name,surname** , так же как и у **B**. Как вывести все name и surname в одной таблице из **A** и **B**,кроме тех которых имеют обе таблицы.
Пример: A{1,2,3} , B{5,1,7} , результат R должен быть {2,3,5,7} (то есть кроме единицы) 
Следует использовать такие операторы вроде EXCEPT,UNION ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select coalesce(A.name,B.name) as name,
       coalesce(A.surname,B.surname) as surname
  from A
  full join B on A.name=B.name and A.surname=B.surname
 where (A.name is null and A.surname is null)
    or (B.name is null and B.surname is null)
```

Как подсказка по использованию EXCEPT и UNION общий вид запроса `select * from (A except B) X union all select * from (B except A) Y`. Но я бы сказал, что такой подход использовать *не следует* ибо вместо одного соединения используются сначала два except, каждый из которых по сложности такой же как это объединение, а потом еще и union. плюс двойное сканирование обоих таблиц.